# C# solving system of quadratic equations

Tags: c#, equation

How do you solve this type of equation?

```
a *X + b * Y + c *Z = q
d *X + e * Y + f *Z = w
X *X + Y * Y + Z *Z = z
```

We are looking for X,Y,Z.  If not the squares in the last row this could be solved as a typical linear equation, for example using Linear Equations from Dot Numerics, or writing Gauss Elimination.
But how do I solve this one?  Also, do you know any libraries in .NET that solves that equation?

Comment: Are these really quadratic equations?  `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`

Comment: It is not the duplicate of the link above! You can't solve this one as normal LinearEquation (using for example DotNumerics) as other linear equations

Comment: This is what happens when moderators do not read carefully questions and close the question with wrong argument...

Comment: How is the linked question not a duplicate?  The OP there is trying to accomplish exactly the same thing you're doing, and the example they give is the same as yours, in every detail.

Comment: My have a quadratic equation in the last row. You can't solve this kind of euqation using Gaussian or any of these methods. X,Y,Z are what we are looking for and they are squared.

Comment: you can by simple algebra convert this to a single quadratc equation in one of the variables, then use the quadratic formuala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be viewed as a set of equations for 2 planes and a sphere.  The solution finds the intersection of the 2 planes (a line) and then the intersection of that line with the sphere.

There may be 0, 1, or 2 unique solutions.

The code is C, but I assume OP can readily translate to c#

```
// Eq1: a *X + b * Y + c *Z = q
// Eq2: d *X + e * Y + f *Z = w
// Eq3: X *X + Y * Y + Z *Z = z
typedef struct {
  double x,y,z,s;
} plane_t;

typedef struct {
  double x,y,z;
} point_t;

int Interection_PlanePlaneSphere(point_t XYZ[2], const plane_t *abc, const plane_t *def, double radius) {
  // Find intersection of 2 planes
  // V = abc cross def
  point_t V;  // This is really 3D vector, not a point
  V.x = abc->y*def->z - abc->z*def->y;
  V.y = abc->z*def->x - abc->x*def->z;
  V.z = abc->x*def->y - abc->y*def->x;
  // printf("V (%12g, %12g, %12g)\n", V.x, V.y, V.z);

  // Assume both planes go through z plane, e.g. z = 0 and V.z != 0
  // Code could be adapted to not depend on this assumption.
  // abc->x*P.x + abc->y*P.y = abc->s
  // def->x*P.x + def->y*P.y = def->s
  double det = abc->x*def->y - abc->y*def->x;

  // if Planes are parallel ...
  // Code could be adapted to deal with special case where planes are coincident.
  if (det == 0.0) return 0;  // 
  point_t P;
  P.x = ( abc->s*def->y - def->s*abc->y)/det;
  P.y = (-abc->s*def->x + def->s*abc->x)/det;
  P.z = 0.0;
  // L(t) = P + V*t = intersection of the 2 planes
  // printf("p (%12g, %12g, %12g)\n", P.x, P.y, P.z);

  if (radius < 0) return 0; // bad sphere
  // Find where L(t) is on the sphere, or |L(t)| = radius^2
  // (P.x - V.x*t)^2 + (P.y - V.y*t)^2 + (P.z - V.z*t)^2 = radius^2
  // (V.x^2 + V.y^2 + V.z^2)*t^2 - 2*(P.x*V.x + P.y*V.y + P.z*V.z) + (P.x^2 + P.y^2 + P.z^2) = radius^2;
  // Solve quadratic
  double a, b, c;
  a = V.x*V.x + V.y*V.y + V.z*V.z;
  b = -2*(P.x*V.x + P.y*V.y + P.z*V.z);
  c = P.x*P.x + P.y*P.y + P.z*P.z - radius*radius;
  // printf("abc (%12g, %12g, %12g)\n", a, b, c);
  det = b*b - 4*a*c;
  if (det < 0) return 0; // no solutions
  det = sqrt(det);
  double t;
  t = (-b + det)/(2*a);
  XYZ[0].x = P.x + t*V.x;
  XYZ[0].y = P.y + t*V.y;
  XYZ[0].z = P.z + t*V.z;
  if (det == 0.0) return 1;
  t = (-b - det)/(2*a);
  XYZ[1].x = P.x + t*V.x;
  XYZ[1].y = P.y + t*V.y;
  XYZ[1].z = P.z + t*V.z;
  return 2;
}

void Test() {
  plane_t abcq = {2, -1,  1, 5};
  plane_t defw = {1,  1, -1, 1};
  double z = 100;
  point_t XYZ[2];
  int result = Interection_PlanePlaneSphere(XYZ, &abcq, &defw, sqrt(z));
  printf("Result %d\n", result);
  int i=0;
  for (i=0; i<result; i++) {
    printf("XYZ[%d] (%12g, %12g, %12g)\n", i, XYZ[i].x, XYZ[i].y, XYZ[i].z);
  }
  // Result 2
  // XYZ[0] (           2,      5.41014,      6.41014)
  // XYZ[1] (           2,     -8.41014,     -7.41014)
}
```